# Is it possible to create a calendar in a Chatter group?

Tags: lightning-web-components, chatter, lightning-events, activities, calendar

I was curious if anyone has ever been able to create a calendar in a Chatter group?  I have looked online, but didn't find any information on this topic.  I am trying to create a calendar in a Chatter group to tie events in the Activities related list to appear in the Calendar based on Account criteria (checkbox field to identify the specific Account).

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000Gddy1UAB/chatter-group-shared-calendar

Answer (score -1):

It's best, in my experience, to use a third-party calendar application, like Google Calendar or Outlook Calendar .These tools let you make calendars, share them with others, and connect them to salesforce .To sync the calendar with salesforce , for instance, you might make a Google Calendar for your Chatter group and utilize the Google Calendar Connector for salesforce.

You can add events to the calendar from salesforce after the calendar and salesforce have been synced. The calendar remainder function can also be used to inform your group members about impending activities.

You might use a workflow rule to link events in the activities linked list to make them show in  the calendar depending on account criteria.